# How to call keyup function on textbox for every dynamic generated form in Angular8

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript, angular8

I am generating form dynamically, on textbox,  I am binding  calculateBCT function like below
`<input matInput type="text" (keyup)="calculateBCT($event)" formControlName="avgBCT">` and returning result on  below textbox with ngModel.

```
<input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="calculatedResult" formControlName="avgCapacity">.
```

**Expected output -**  If i will enter **value in Textbox0**, it will call **calculateBCT function** and reflect result in **Result0 textbox** only, When i will enter value in **Textbox1** it will call **calculateBCT function** and reflect result in **Result1 textbox** likewise..

Can anyone help me to get expected output

[Here i have created stackblitz demo with code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qwyst8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, and see if it helps.

In **app.component.html**, make below changes:

- Remove `[(ngModel)]="calculatedResult"` as you are already using `formControlName`
- Pass index `i` to calculateBCT as `(keyup)="calculateBCT($event, i)"`

In **app.component.ts**, modify the calculateBCT method as:

```ts
    calculateBCT($event, index: number) {
      // Your existing logic goes here...
      const calculatedResult = result ? result : 0;
      // In below code, please put some checks to ensure that formControl does exist
      const formControl = this.itemTypes().at(index).get('avgCapacity');
      formControl.setValue(calculatedResult);
    }
```

**Edit:**

Since you already have formGroup available in html file, you can simply pass `lineItem` as 2nd parameter to `calculateBCT` and access formControl as `const formControl = lineItem.get('avgCapacity');`